# Web logic thread dump analysis : HttpSession is invalid

Tags: weblogic, thread-dump

Hi I am very new to thread dump analysis so please excuse. There was an increase in WL queue, while trying to analyze I got this below error, several(more than 1000) times.

Can anybody help me what is the issue with the below one, and how does sessions got invalidated? Is this a potential issue?

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '173' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <guest> <> <> <1472479201177> <BEA-100025> <An unexpected error occurred in HTTP session timeout callback while deleting sessions.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpSession is invalid
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getInternalAttribute(SessionData.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getInternalAttribute(SessionData.java:785)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.invalidateSession(SessionContext.java:1067)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.access$400(SessionContext.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.cleanupExpiredSessions(SessionContext.java:1001)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator$1.run(SessionContext.java:903)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.timerExpired(SessionContext.java:897)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```